# can we send post parameters with webview url in javafx

Tags: javafx-2

I am making an application of javafx, in which I need to call the fxbrowser with some post parameter, so that on server side we can verify the user and generate the response according to that.

We can send data by just `url?p1=v1&p2=v2....`

But Is it possible to call `webengine.load(url)` with some post parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need web automation library to fill form and submit. You could use [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) which is wrapper to JavaFX WebView component.

Check this [BingSearch](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j/blob/master/ui4j-sample/src/main/java/com/ui4j/sample/BingSearch.java) example which submits form and extracts the search result.

Comment: thanks Duz for replying, I did it without using ui4j by just making a html page and inserted all the parameter by html hidden field and grammatically submitted the page with action='url'